# d3js bar graph with x+y axes: x axis value distribution

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, axes

I'm trying to show a vertical bar chart with x and y axes. I get the bar chart with y axis, however I'm struggling with the x-axis.

The x-axis text labels are equally distributed with the width of the bars, however: there are markers/vertical lines on the x-axis with varying width, particularly the first and last sections, even though I've specified the `scaleBand` and the `domain`.

My code:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg class="v5chart" width="960" height="500"></svg>

<style>
/*Rectangle bar class styling*/
.bar {
  fill: #0080FF
}
.bar:hover {
  fill: #003366
}

/*Text class styling*/
.text {
  fill: white;
  font-family: sans-serif
}
</style>

<script>

////VERTICAL BAR CHART WITH SVG AND NAMES
// Create data array of values to visualize
var dataArray = [{ "Player": "John Doe", "Points": 23 }, { "Player": "Jane Doe", "Points": 13 }, { "Player": "Mary Jane", "Points": 21 }, { "Player": "Debasis Das", "Points": 14 }, { "Player": "Nishant", "Points": 37 }, { "Player": "Mark", "Points": 15 }, { "Player": "Andrew", "Points": 18 }, { "Player": "Simon", "Points": 34 }, { "Player": "Lisa", "Points": 30 }, { "Player": "Marga", "Points": 20 }];

// Create variable for the SVG
var canvas = d3.select(".v5chart1").append("g").attr("transform", "translate(20,30)");

var canvasWidth = 500;


var maxValue = d3.max(dataArray, function (d) { return d.Points; });
var canvasHeight = maxValue*10;

var heightScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataArray, function (d) { return d.Points; })])
    .range([canvasHeight, 0]); //use max value (37) * 10

var y_axis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(heightScale);

var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, canvasWidth], .1);

x.domain(dataArray.map(function (d) { return d.Player; }));

var x_Axis = d3.axisBottom(x);

// Select, append to SVG, and add attributes to rectangles for bar chart
canvas.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataArray)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("height", function (d, i) { return (d.Points * 10) })
    .attr("width", canvasWidth/dataArray.length)    
    .attr("x", function (d, i) { return (i * (canvasWidth / dataArray.length)) })
    .attr("y", function (d, i) { return canvasHeight - (d.Points * 10) });

// Select, append to SVG, and add attributes to text
canvas.selectAll("text")
    .data(dataArray)
    .enter().append("text")
    .text(function (d) { return d.Points })
    .attr("class", "text")
    .attr("x", function (d, i) { return (i * (canvasWidth / dataArray.length)) + (canvasWidth / dataArray.length)/2 })
    .attr("y", function (d, i) { return canvasHeight + 20 - (d.Points * 10) });



canvas.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .call(y_axis);

canvas.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + canvasHeight + ")")
    .call(x_Axis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("x",40)
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "rotate(65)"
    });

</script>
```

I already checked here: https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/custom_axis.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have read properly the `scaleBand` example on the link that you provided:

- `scaleBand` provides a convenient `bandwidth()` method to provide you with the width for each bar
- the idea od axis in `d3js` is that you don't need to do calculations yourself, so in your case you can just pass the player name to the `x` function and it will do the coordinate calculations for you.
- same applies to the `y` calculations, but I leave this for you to figure out, it should not be hard at all.
- one more small thing about `scaleBand`, you were using `rangeRound()` method, which I am not familiar with, but if you use `range()` method combined with `padding()` as it is in the example you linked, then by adjusting the padding value you can control the width of the bar, without affecting the x axis. The higher value, the thinner will be the bar and more space would be between the bars.

```js
////VERTICAL BAR CHART WITH SVG AND NAMES
        // Create data array of values to visualize
        var dataArray = [{ "Player": "John Doe", "Points": 23 }, { "Player": "Jane Doe", "Points": 13 }, { "Player": "Mary Jane", "Points": 21 }, { "Player": "Debasis Das", "Points": 14 }, { "Player": "Nishant", "Points": 37 }, { "Player": "Mark", "Points": 15 }, { "Player": "Andrew", "Points": 18 }, { "Player": "Simon", "Points": 34 }, { "Player": "Lisa", "Points": 30 }, { "Player": "Marga", "Points": 20 }];
    
        // Create variable for the SVG
        var canvas = d3.select(".v5chart").append("g").attr("transform", "translate(20,30)");
    
        var canvasWidth = 500;
    
        var maxValue = d3.max(dataArray, function (d) { return d.Points; });
    
        var heightScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(dataArray, function (d) { return d.Points; })])
            .range([maxValue * 10, 0]); //use max value (37) * 10
    
        var y_axis = d3.axisLeft()
            .scale(heightScale);
    
        var x = d3.scaleBand()
            .range([0, canvasWidth]).padding([0.1]);
    
        x.domain(dataArray.map(function (d) { return d.Player; }));
       
        var x_Axis = d3.axisBottom(x);
    
        // Select, append to SVG, and add attributes to rectangles for bar chart
        canvas.selectAll("rect")
            .data(dataArray)
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("height", function (d, i) { return (d.Points * 10) })
            .attr("width", x.bandwidth())    
            .attr("x", function (d, i) { return x(d.Player); })
            .attr("y", function (d, i) { return 370 - (d.Points * 10) });
    
        // Select, append to SVG, and add attributes to text
        canvas.selectAll("text")
            .data(dataArray)
            .enter().append("text")
            .text(function (d) { return d.Points })
            .attr("class", "text")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("x", function (d, i) { return x(d.Player)+x.bandwidth()/2; })
            .attr("y", function (d, i) { return 390 - (d.Points * 10) });
    
    canvas.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
        .call(y_axis);

    canvas.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,370)")
        .call(x_Axis);
```

```css
.bar {
      fill: #0080FF
    }
    .bar:hover {
      fill: #003366
    }
    
    /*Text class styling*/
    .text {
      fill: white;
      font-family: sans-serif
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
    <svg class="v5chart" width="960" height="500"></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! One follow-up question then: right now I align the points (white text) in the bars centrally through `.attr("x", function (d, i) { return (i * (canvasWidth / dataArray.length)) + (canvasWidth / dataArray.length) / 2 })`. With your new example that alignment fails. How can I make sure that text is in the horizontal middle of bar? Thanks!

Comment: @Flo Same way I am aligning the bars themselves in my example! Always use `x` and `y` function to determine positions

Comment: Not sure how then, I tried `.attr("x", function (d, i) { return x(d.Player); })` and `.attr("x", function (d, i) { return (x(d.Player) + x.bandwidth()/2); })`. Neither align the text in the center...

Comment: @Flo For future I strongly suggest to ask a separate issue as a separate question - this way your chances for someone else to answer the question go up! Regarding the text issue, I have update my answer. I also suggest you to take a look at http://bl.ocks.org/emmasaunders/d682fd84b67b304219e49b1e8385b1f8 to understand how the text anchoring works in d3js. Happy New Year! :)